# When does a distribution and an integral commute?

Tags: distribution-theory

I am working on a problem, and got stuck at this point.

Suppose that $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a distribution, $\phi_y \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and the map $\psi: y \mapsto u[\phi_y]$ is smooth, further $(D^{\alpha} \psi)(y) = (D^\alpha u)[ \phi_y]$ Can we say that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \psi(y) \ dy = u \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \phi_y(x) \ dx \right]$$
I suspect that the answer is yes, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to read. There seems to be some mix up between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: See the definition of the tensor product of distributions. Here you have $u\otimes 1$. The expressions are defined and equal if $\phi(x, y)\in {\cal D}({\mathbb R}^{2n})$

Comment: Is there any way we can do it without that? In my course we have not used that definition. I suspect it was intended to be solved by using the Fourier transform in some way, but I am not sure.